# Android Change iptable rules in android source code

Tags: android, iptables

Does anybody know how to change iptables rules in android source code or android linux kernel code or android image?

I want to apply these following rules in android image

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

Do i need to create any system level native app? if anybody know the answer or done anything like that please help me out.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

You need to have root access and you can run the commands. Check this example code to run your commands:

https://github.com/joanpuigsanz/servdroid/blob/master/android/ServDroid.web/src/org/servDroid/util/shell/ShellCommands.java

Comment: But i want to implement this change in android open source code and not through any command so that change reflect directly in Android image.

Comment: Then you will need to reinvent the wheel creating some C/C++ code that access the IPtables data and linked it to your code using JNI, there is no connection between the SDK and the system firewall

Answer (score 1):

For android 9.0. please modify the android source file: external/iptables/etc/xtables.conf
Rebuild android system image.

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is a good answer or should rather be a comment... I came here from review, as this is a late answer... I'll just leave it here ^^